# Python Pmw and cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, exe, freeze, cx-freeze

I am unable to make an executable from my python program which uses Pmw (Python mega widgets). I use cx_Freeze (through gui backend "Gui2Exe"). Searching Pmw site I've found that it's caused by how the Pmw library checks for modules when ran and it doesn't work when you use py2exe or similar programs because the libraries are in a zip file. More info can be found here: http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/dynamicloader.html
So they give a solution in that page, under "Freezing Pmw", by providing a script which generates a single standalone Pmw module which you can easily freeze. However, that script uses deprecated code and won't work with Python 2.6 +. I've tried to modify it with no luck.

EDIT: I'd like to mention that just replacing 'regex' with 're' won't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Helper script when freezing Pmw applications.  It concatenates all
# Pmw megawidget files into a single file, 'Pmw.py', in the current
# directory.  The script must be called with one argument, being the
# path to the 'lib' directory of the required version of Pmw.
# To freeze a Pmw application, you will also need to copy the
# following files to the application directory before freezing:
#
#    PmwBlt.py PmwColor.py

import os
import regsub
import string
import sys

# The order of these files is significant.  Files which reference
# other files must appear later.  Files may be deleted if they are not
# used.
files = [
    'Dialog', 'TimeFuncs', 'Balloon', 'ButtonBox', 'EntryField',
    'Group', 'LabeledWidget', 'MainMenuBar', 'MenuBar', 'MessageBar',
    'MessageDialog', 'NoteBook', 'OptionMenu', 'PanedWidget', 'PromptDialog',
    'RadioSelect', 'ScrolledCanvas', 'ScrolledField', 'ScrolledFrame',
    'ScrolledListBox', 'ScrolledText', 'HistoryText', 'SelectionDialog',
    'TextDialog', 'TimeCounter', 'AboutDialog', 'ComboBox', 'ComboBoxDialog',
    'Counter', 'CounterDialog',
]

# Set this to 0 if you do not use any of the Pmw.Color functions:
needColor = 1

# Set this to 0 if you do not use any of the Pmw.Blt functions:
needBlt = 1

def expandLinks(path):
    if not os.path.isabs(path):
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path)
    while 1:
    if not os.path.islink(path):
        break
    dir = os.path.dirname(path)
    path = os.path.join(dir, os.readlink(path))

    return path

def mungeFile(file):
    # Read the file and modify it so that it can be bundled with the
    # other Pmw files.
    file = 'Pmw' + file + '.py'
    text = open(os.path.join(srcdir, file)).read()
    text = regsub.gsub('import Pmw\>', '', text)
    text = regsub.gsub('INITOPT = Pmw.INITOPT', '', text)
    text = regsub.gsub('\<Pmw\.', '', text)
    text = '\n' + ('#' * 70) + '\n' + '### File: ' + file + '\n' + text
    return text

# Work out which version is being bundled.
file = sys.argv[0]
file = os.path.normpath(file)
file = expandLinks(file)

dir = os.path.dirname(file)
dir = expandLinks(dir)
dir = os.path.dirname(dir)
dir = expandLinks(dir)
dir = os.path.basename(dir)

version = string.replace(dir[4:], '_', '.')

# Code to import the Color module.
colorCode = """
import PmwColor
Color = PmwColor
del PmwColor
"""

# Code to import the Blt module.
bltCode = """
import PmwBlt
Blt = PmwBlt
del PmwBlt
"""

# Code used when not linking with PmwBlt.py.
ignoreBltCode = """
_bltImported = 1
_bltbusyOK = 0
"""

# Code to define the functions normally supplied by the dynamic loader.
extraCode = """

### Loader functions:

_VERSION = '%s'

def setversion(version):
    if version != _VERSION:
        raise ValueError, 'Dynamic versioning not available'

def setalphaversions(*alpha_versions):
    if alpha_versions != ():
    raise ValueError, 'Dynamic versioning not available'

def version(alpha = 0):
    if alpha:
        return ()
    else:
        return _VERSION

def installedversions(alpha = 0):
    if alpha:
        return ()
    else:
        return (_VERSION,)

"""

if '-noblt' in sys.argv:
    sys.argv.remove('-noblt')
    needBlt = 0

if '-nocolor' in sys.argv:
    sys.argv.remove('-nocolor')
    needColor = 0

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'usage: bundlepmw.py [-noblt] [-nocolor] /path/to/Pmw/Pmw_X_X_X/lib'
    sys.exit()

srcdir = sys.argv[1]

if os.path.exists('Pmw.py'):
    print 'Pmw.py already exists. Remove it and try again.'
    sys.exit()

outfile = open('Pmw.py', 'w')

if needColor:
    outfile.write(colorCode)

if needBlt:
    outfile.write(bltCode)

outfile.write(extraCode % version)

# Specially handle PmwBase.py file:
text = mungeFile('Base')
text = regsub.gsub('import PmwLogicalFont', '', text)
text = regsub.gsub('PmwLogicalFont._font_initialise', '_font_initialise', text)
outfile.write(text)
if not needBlt:
    outfile.write(ignoreBltCode)

files.append('LogicalFont')
for file in files:
    text = mungeFile(file)
    outfile.write(text)

print ''
print '   Pmw.py has been created.'

if needColor or needBlt:
    print '   Before running freeze, also copy the following file(s):'
    if needBlt:
    print '   ' + os.path.join(srcdir, 'PmwBlt.py')
    if needColor:
    print '   ' + os.path.join(srcdir, 'PmwColor.py')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the original file has some problems with tabs and spaces (just look at the `while` indentation in `expandlinks`).

I fixed those indentation problems, changed `regsub.gsub` with `re.sub` and eliminated the `string` import, using the string type methods.

After that the script worked perfect:

```
   Pmw.py has been created.
   Before running freeze, also copy the following file(s):
   C:\Users\joaquin\Desktop\Pmw.1.3.2\src\Pmw\Pmw_1_3\lib\PmwBlt.py
   C:\Users\joaquin\Desktop\Pmw.1.3.2\src\Pmw\Pmw_1_3\lib\PmwColor.py
```

Here you have the corrected script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Helper script when freezing Pmw applications.  It concatenates all
# Pmw megawidget files into a single file, 'Pmw.py', in the current
# directory.  The script must be called with one argument, being the
# path to the 'lib' directory of the required version of Pmw.
# To freeze a Pmw application, you will also need to copy the
# following files to the application directory before freezing:
#
#    PmwBlt.py PmwColor.py

import os
import re
import sys

# The order of these files is significant.  Files which reference
# other files must appear later.  Files may be deleted if they are not
# used.
files = [
    'Dialog', 'TimeFuncs', 'Balloon', 'ButtonBox', 'EntryField',
    'Group', 'LabeledWidget', 'MainMenuBar', 'MenuBar', 'MessageBar',
    'MessageDialog', 'NoteBook', 'OptionMenu', 'PanedWidget', 'PromptDialog',
    'RadioSelect', 'ScrolledCanvas', 'ScrolledField', 'ScrolledFrame',
    'ScrolledListBox', 'ScrolledText', 'HistoryText', 'SelectionDialog',
    'TextDialog', 'TimeCounter', 'AboutDialog', 'ComboBox', 'ComboBoxDialog',
    'Counter', 'CounterDialog',
]

# Set this to 0 if you do not use any of the Pmw.Color functions:
needColor = 1

# Set this to 0 if you do not use any of the Pmw.Blt functions:
needBlt = 1

def expandLinks(path):
    if not os.path.isabs(path):
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path)
    while 1:
        if not os.path.islink(path):
            break
        dir = os.path.dirname(path)
        path = os.path.join(dir, os.readlink(path))

    return path

def mungeFile(file):
    # Read the file and modify it so that it can be bundled with the
    # other Pmw files.
    file = 'Pmw' + file + '.py'
    text = open(os.path.join(srcdir, file)).read()
    text = re.sub('import Pmw\>', '', text)
    text = re.sub('INITOPT = Pmw.INITOPT', '', text)
    text = re.sub('\<Pmw\.', '', text)
    text = '\n' + ('#' * 70) + '\n' + '### File: ' + file + '\n' + text
    return text

# Work out which version is being bundled.
file = sys.argv[0]
file = os.path.normpath(file)
file = expandLinks(file)

dir = os.path.dirname(file)
dir = expandLinks(dir)
dir = os.path.dirname(dir)
dir = expandLinks(dir)
dir = os.path.basename(dir)

version = dir[4:].replace('_', '.')

# Code to import the Color module.
colorCode = """
import PmwColor
Color = PmwColor
del PmwColor
"""
# Code to import the Blt module.
bltCode = """
import PmwBlt
Blt = PmwBlt
del PmwBlt
"""
# Code used when not linking with PmwBlt.py.
ignoreBltCode = """
_bltImported = 1
_bltbusyOK = 0
"""
# Code to define the functions normally supplied by the dynamic loader.
extraCode = """

### Loader functions:

_VERSION = '%s'

def setversion(version):
    if version != _VERSION:
        raise ValueError, 'Dynamic versioning not available'

def setalphaversions(*alpha_versions):
    if alpha_versions != ():
        raise ValueError, 'Dynamic versioning not available'

def version(alpha = 0):
    if alpha:
        return ()
    else:
        return _VERSION

def installedversions(alpha = 0):
    if alpha:
        return ()
    else:
        return (_VERSION,)

"""
if '-noblt' in sys.argv:
    sys.argv.remove('-noblt')
    needBlt = 0

if '-nocolor' in sys.argv:
    sys.argv.remove('-nocolor')
    needColor = 0

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'usage: bundlepmw.py [-noblt] [-nocolor] /path/to/Pmw/Pmw_X_X_X/lib'
    sys.exit()

srcdir = sys.argv[1]

if os.path.exists('Pmw.py'):
    print 'Pmw.py already exists. Remove it and try again.'
    sys.exit()

outfile = open('Pmw.py', 'w')

if needColor:
    outfile.write(colorCode)

if needBlt:
    outfile.write(bltCode)

outfile.write(extraCode % version)

# Specially handle PmwBase.py file:
text = mungeFile('Base')
text = re.sub('import PmwLogicalFont', '', text)
text = re.sub('PmwLogicalFont._font_initialise', '_font_initialise', text)
outfile.write(text)
if not needBlt:
    outfile.write(ignoreBltCode)

files.append('LogicalFont')
for file in files:
    text = mungeFile(file)
    outfile.write(text)

print ''
print '   Pmw.py has been created.'

if needColor or needBlt:
    print '   Before running freeze, also copy the following file(s):'
    if needBlt:
        print '   ' + os.path.join(srcdir, 'PmwBlt.py')
    if needColor:
        print '   ' + os.path.join(srcdir, 'PmwColor.py')
```

Comment: Great. I'll try it now. I suggest contact the Pmw developers to add the changes. Well you made it thats why I'm saying, if you don't have the time I could do it for you.

Comment: @Brock123, It is not necessary. I checked the site and although it seems abandonware, a contributor, gruber, updated the script months ago and put it in the [cvs sourceforge repository](http://pmw.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pmw/Pmw/Pmw_0_0_0/bin/bundlepmw.py?revision=1.3&view=markup)

Comment: could u guys pls explain it for me, i dont get it , im a beginer