# FileNotFoundError when starting an Exe

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I have created a GUI with Tkinter, which includes tooltips. For the creation of the tooltips I used the package [Pmw.Balloon](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/Balloon.html)

When I create an executable with Pyinstaller from the script and start the exe, I get a FileNotFoundError:

[image]

I use Anaconda-Jupyter Notebook and have installed all Python packages (including Pmw) in one environment. Does anyone of you know how I can fix this error?

### Edit 2:

I thing i found the reason for the error. Pyinstaller is not including/loading the Pmw package.

### Edit 1:

This FileNotFoundEroor is only raised from the exe and not when the main Python file is directly executed.

Further information when the exe is created:

```
(base) C:\Users\....\Desktop\Code>pyinstaller --onefile test.py
207 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
208 INFO: Python: 3.7.4 (conda)
209 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
225 INFO: wrote C:\Users\....\Desktop\Code\test.spec
232 INFO: UPX is not available.
236 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\Code', 'C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\Code']
237 INFO: checking Analysis
238 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
238 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
262 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
288 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
12229 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
12637 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
12685 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
14030 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\....\Desktop\Code\test.py
16703 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
16709 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\....\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\anaconda3\\lib'
20840 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
20845 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\....\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
27447 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
48638 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
65399 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
122663 INFO: Processing module hooks...
122663 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-babel.py"...
122929 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
122936 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-Crypto.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto.Math'
123126 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cryptography.py"...
124300 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
124306 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-docutils.py"...
129334 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
129546 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-importlib_metadata.py"...
129558 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-IPython.py"...
132300 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
132310 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module IPython.lib.clipboard
132312 INFO: Excluding import 'gtk'
132323 INFO: Excluding import 'matplotlib'
132335 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib._pylab_helpers from module IPython.core.pylabtools
132336 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.figure from module IPython.core.pylabtools
132337 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib from module IPython.core.pylabtools
132338 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.pyplot from module IPython.core.pylabtools
132343 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
132355 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
132357 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
132370 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
132372 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
132381 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtSvg from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
132381 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtWidgets from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
132383 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
132384 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
132385 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
132388 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jedi.py"...
132886 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jinja2.py"...
132995 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jsonschema.py"...
133011 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
133023 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.backends.py"...
136628 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
137407 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
138701 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py)
141186 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": added
143339 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
144384 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
145837 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
146807 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
148102 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
149156 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
150342 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
151462 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
152388 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
153343 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
154339 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
155198 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
156241 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
157287 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
158123 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
158968 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
160022 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
160810 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.py"...
161561 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-nbconvert.py"...
161610 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-nbformat.py"...
161630 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-notebook.py"...
166746 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
166991 INFO: MKL libraries found when importing numpy. Adding MKL to binaries
167001 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
167006 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
168235 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
168246 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
168251 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
168255 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
168256 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
168263 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module PIL.ImageQt
168264 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
168271 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module PIL.ImageQt
168273 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
168279 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
168279 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
168281 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
168293 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
168298 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
168298 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
169883 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
170754 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
170759 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
170759 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pycparser.py"...
170764 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
170770 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pygments.py"...
175041 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
176374 WARNING: Hidden import "PyQt5.sip" not found!
176374 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
176799 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
177238 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py"...
178125 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
178871 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytest.py"...
181453 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
182802 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytz.py"...
183007 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
184144 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.linalg.py"...
184149 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.py"...
184156 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py"...
184170 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py"...
184174 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py"...
184179 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
186259 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sphinx.py"...
200804 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
201025 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
201030 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
202494 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
202499 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
202504 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
202511 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-zmq.py"...
207967 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
208496 INFO: checking Tree
208496 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
208497 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
208735 INFO: checking Tree
208735 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
208736 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
208775 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-gevent.py"...
209451 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
370757 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement greenlet from package gevent.
370757 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['cffi']
375108 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lxml.etree.py"...
375550 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
375901 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
375937 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
375946 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
375957 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
375970 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_traitlets.py'
375978 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_certifi.py'
375986 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
375995 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
376002 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
376010 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
376131 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
377279 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.dll
377306 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
377839 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.dll
379576 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
379578 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
379581 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
381124 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll
381172 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
381279 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll
387553 INFO: Looking for eggs
387554 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\python37.dll
387555 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
387632 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\....\Desktop\Code\build\test\warn-test.txt
388866 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\....\Desktop\Code\build\test\xref-test.html
389262 INFO: checking PYZ
389262 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
389265 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\....\Desktop\Code\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz
395965 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\....\Desktop\Code\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
396257 INFO: checking PKG
396257 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
396258 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
575871 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
576232 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
576233 INFO: checking EXE
576234 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
576236 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
576238 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\....\Desktop\Code\dist\test.exe
576660 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: If this error is only raised when you run the exec output of Pyinstaller, then it means the Pythinstaller options used to bundle the app are missing some information of some resource. It helps if you could share how the exe is created (exact details of Pyinstaller conf), and if this issue is only raised from the exe and not when the main Python file is directly executed.

Comment: @farzad i updated my initial post with further information

Comment: im having d same issue and no better answers yet :( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40559477/create-a-python-3-exe-with-pyinstaller-with-pmw-module) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772916/python-pmw-and-cx-freeze) are the only helping ones so far but its complicated